# Compile yii based project and use it as a single binary file?

Tags: php, yii, compilation

I know that it is possible to compile php codes and use them. I also know that there is some techniques to use php compiled files in .NET.

I have made a project with Yii framework and I need to run a demo of my project some period of time before my customers decide to buy it or not.

I want to know if there is any way to compile a Yii based project to a single binary file and use it standalone or with Apache or IIS.
If there is no such a way, could I close Yii based project source code in a manner?

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile a PHP script into some sort of a portable binary file, with Yii framework it shouldn't be any different, as the Yii framework is still a collection of PHP script files.

This question has already been answered here in Stackoverflow: [Convert PHP file to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845197/convert-php-file-to-binary)